# How to implode an array to new lines

Tags: php, arrays, newline, implode

I have an array as such.

```
$array = array();
$array[] = 'how';
$array[] = 'are';
$array[] = 'you';
```

I tried both `echo implode( "\n", $array ); exit; die;` and `echo implode( PHP_EOL, $array ); exit; die;` but it always outputs on the same line and not like:

how
are
you

How can I implode the array to new lines?

Comment: Do you look at the results in the browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using echo to display the imploded array, use `<br>` instead of `\n`

```
echo implode( "<br>", $array );
```

Since PHP renders echo outputs as HTML markups, whereas if you use `\n`, and view the page source, you will be able to see the words printed on separate lines in the page source instead of on the actual webpage.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works just fine.  See it in action here (where it DOES show in multiple lines).

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac32618898919ef1eae8b0012fbcb83b03a30f26

It really just depends on how you're displaying the data.  For example, if you're trying to create HTML, change `"\n"` to `"<br>"`.

But overall, there's nothing wrong with how you wrote it.  Likely just a mismatch of the linebreak you're using and how you're displaying it.